# Manually laid out view in auto layout super view

Tags: ios, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I have some not so ordinary problem related to mixing of Auto Layout and  Manual layout.

1. **view1** - super view that uses auto layout
2. **view2** - subview that uses manual layout

**view1**'s height depends on the total height of the subviews.

I set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO` and `frame` for **view2** and add it as subview to the **view1** . The resulted height of **view2** is 0 (in the `layoutSubviews`)

So, the auto layout of the **view1** doesn't pay attention to the **view2's** height when determines self height. And then propagate this 0 height to the **view2**.

Need advice. I'm not sure that this is legal.

Comment: You didn't post much code with your answer, so I've got some general comments. You can mix Interface Builder-created views and views created programmatically. There are several ways to do it, but I think the easiest way is with Visual Format Language. This tutorial is a good starting point. http://www.raywenderlich.com/110393/auto-layout-visual-format-language-tutorial

Comment: How can be mixed views created programmatically but with different layout engines? Not so many tutorials in google :(

Comment: Not sure that code will be appropriate here, but I can draw scheme, if my description is not clear enough.

Comment: As you said `superview size equals` to `subview size`, How the OS knows about dependancy between `SuperView (View1)` and subview `(view2)` without specifying autolayout?

Comment: super view creates constraints with 0 constants to subview's top/bottom/trailing/leading edges. So it's size depends on the size of subview, which size determined using manual layout (set `frame`)

Comment: as you said you given `frame` for subview. and `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO` then How `SuperView ` will find the `width` and `height`

Comment: Normally `frame` assigned at runtime either try `layoutSubviews` may solve your issue. Better to give the constraints programatically.

Comment: @Rafeek, thanks, I think you've shown me the way to understand the issue. I've set height constraint for `view2` before inserting it into `view1` as subview. Please, create an answer with your last 2 comments, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In auto layout world, the view should have unambiguous set of constraints. So, to embed view that was created using manual layout into view that was created using auto layout, either you or iOS system has to provide correspondent constraints' set for subview.

In other words:

- set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES`, configure `frame` and `autoresizingMask` as you usually do. But pay attention to a possible conflicts between constraints that super view already has and constraints that will be created by operation system during translation of autoresizing mask into constraints (at runtime).
- set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO` and add constraints by yourself.

Well, nothing new. But I had to spent some time to figure it out in my head and hope it would save your time!